# Is facebook share intent on android still broken?

Tags: android, facebook, url, android-intent

This question is related to this one:
[Share Text on Facebook from Android App via ACTION_SEND](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3515198/share-text-on-facebook-from-android-app-via-action-send)

When i want to share a link which doesn't end in .php or .html, the facebook app strips the path of my url:

`https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3515198/share-text-on-facebook-from-android-app-via-action-send`

will become

```
https://stackoverflow.com/
```

Has anyone else met this bug? Should I open it in Facebook bug tracker?

Comment: Yes - facing the same issue. Even EXTRA_SUBJECT and EXTRA_TEXT are being ignored.

Answer (score 1):

Can't you just add /?.php to the URL most servers wouldn't be fazed by the argument.

Comment: I haven't had the opportunity to try yet, but I will eventually