# Video Sharing on Facebook using the Android share Intent

Tags: android-intent

This problem may look similar but in no way related to "video sharing on Facebook using Facebook sdk" or "sharing plain text or image using the share intent" .
I have followed these posts  on SO ->

[Android share intent for Facebook](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7076717/android-share-intent-for-facebook)

[How to share photo with CAPTION via Android share intent on Facebook?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5214764/how-to-share-photo-with-caption-via-android-share-intent-on-facebook)

and this external link

http://sudarmuthu.com/blog/sharing-content-in-android-using-action_send-intent

and came to know about the share intent in android which can be launched to share the images/videos/text with the existing sharing application on Android Phone.
I  used this code to share the image on facebook :

```
package com.mypackage.share;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;

public class FbshareActivity extends Activity {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        Intent share = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
        share.setType("image/jpg");

        share.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM,Uri.parse("file:///mnt/sdcard/tutu.jpg"));
        startActivity(Intent.createChooser(share, "Share Image"));
    }
}
```

the Manifest file is as below :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.mypackage.share"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="10" />

    <application
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <activity
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:name=".FbshareActivity" >
            <intent-filter >
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

It works fine.I am able to share the image on facebook.

Now I want to upload the video : 
I replaced this line : 
        **share.setType("image/jpg");**

with this
        **share.setType("video/3gpp");**

and this one 
        **share.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM,Uri.parse("**file:///mnt/sdcard/dimg1333456357958.jpg**"));**
with this one
**share.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM,Uri.parse("**file:///mnt/sdcard/a123bghy4.3gpp**"));**

But I am getting this error on running the code :

```
/Environment(30996): getExternalStorageState/mnt/sdcard
E/Environment(30996): getExternalStorageList
W/MountService( 2879): getVolumeState(/mnt/sdcard/external_sd): Unknown volume
W/MountService( 2879): getVolumeState(/mnt/sdcard/external_sd): Unknown volume
E/Environment(30996): getExternalStorageState/mnt/sdcard
D/SurfaceFlinger( 2879): [JJ]removeSurface for sid=74 
D/dalvikvm(30996): GC_CONCURRENT freed 1106K, 19% free 8612K/10503K, paused 3ms+5ms
E/SurfaceFlinger( 2879): [JJ]SurfaceFlinger FPS: 24.994677
D/ACRA    (30996): Writing crash report file.
D/ACRA    (30996): Mark all pending reports as approved.
D/ACRA    (30996): Looking for error files in /data/data/com.facebook.katana/app_acra-reports
V/ACRA    (30996): About to start ReportSenderWorker from #handleException
D/ACRA    (30996): Add user comment to null
D/ACRA    (30996): #checkAndSendReports - start
D/ACRA    (30996): Looking for error files in /data/data/com.facebook.katana/app_acra-reports
I/ACRA    (30996): Sending file 1333628258000-approved.stacktrace
D/ACRA    (30996): Connect to https://www.facebook.com/mobile/android_crash_logs/
D/ACRA    (30996): Setting httpPost headers
D/ACRA    (30996): Sending request to https://www.facebook.com/mobile/android_crash_logs/
D/dalvikvm(30996): GC_CONCURRENT freed 631K, 18% free 8644K/10503K, paused 5ms+2ms
W/ResponseProcessCookies(30996): Invalid cookie header: "Set-Cookie: datr=ZY19T4_v6CV68jQn4FTduX_l; expires=Sat, 05-Apr-2014 12:17:41 GMT; path=/; domain=.facebook.com; httponly". Unable to parse expires attribute: Sat
E/SurfaceFlinger( 2879): [JJ]SurfaceFlinger FPS: 4.741684
D/BatteryService( 2879): update start
D/ACRA    (30996): #checkAndSendReports - finish
E/AndroidRuntime(30996): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
E/AndroidRuntime(30996): java.lang.NullPointerException
E/AndroidRuntime(30996):    at com.facebook.katana.service.method.VideoUpload.getRealPathFromURI(VideoUpload.java:144)
E/AndroidRuntime(30996):    at com.facebook.katana.service.method.VideoUpload.start(VideoUpload.java:165)
E/AndroidRuntime(30996):    at com.facebook.katana.binding.AppSession.postToService(AppSession.java:4212)
E/AndroidRuntime(30996):    at com.facebook.katana.service.method.VideoUpload.RequestVideoUpload(VideoUpload.java:73)
E/AndroidRuntime(30996):    at com.facebook.katana.activity.media.UploadVideoActivity.upload(UploadVideoActivity.java:209)
E/AndroidRuntime(30996):    at com.facebook.katana.activity.media.UploadVideoActivity.onClick(UploadVideoActivity.java:169)
E/AndroidRuntime(30996):    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:3100)
E/AndroidRuntime(30996):    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:11644)
E/AndroidRuntime(30996):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
E/AndroidRuntime(30996):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
E/AndroidRuntime(30996):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:126)
E/AndroidRuntime(30996):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4002)
E/AndroidRuntime(30996):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
E/AndroidRuntime(30996):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:491)
E/AndroidRuntime(30996):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:844)
E/AndroidRuntime(30996):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:602)
E/AndroidRuntime(30996):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
D/SurfaceFlinger( 2879): screenshot: sw=216, sh=135, minZ=0, maxZ=21015
W/ActivityManager( 2879):   Force finishing activity com.facebook.katana/.activity.media.UploadVideoActivity
D/SurfaceFlinger( 2879): screenshot: result = OK
E/android.os.Debug( 2879): Dumpstate > /data/log/dumpstate_app_com_facebook_katana_error
I/dumpstate(31581): begin
W/ActivityManager( 2879): Activity pause timeout for ActivityRecord{40f51e68 com.facebook.katana/.activity.media.UploadVideoActivity}
F//system/bin/logcat(31586): stack corruption detected: aborted
W/PowerManagerService( 2879): Timer 0x3->0x3|0x0
D/VoldCmdListener(   87): asec list
I/dumpstate(31581): done
D/InputTransport( 2879): channel '41014710 Sorry!    - Use *#9900# to take log - (server)' ~ mPointerStates->semaphore initialized 0x586ac000.
D/InputTransport( 2879): channel '41014710 Sorry!    - Use *#9900# to take log - (server)' ~ mPointerStates initialized 0x586ac000.
D/InputTransport( 2879): channel '41014710 Sorry!    - Use *#9900# to take log - (client)' ~ mPointerStates initialized 0x587f1000.
E/SurfaceFlinger( 2879): [JJ]SurfaceFlinger FPS: 0.207880
D/SurfaceFlinger( 2879): [JJ]createSurface for pid 31559 (1280 x 752)
D/SurfaceFlinger( 2879): [JJ]createSurface for pid 2879 (1 x 1)
E/SurfaceFlinger( 2879): [JJ]SurfaceFlinger FPS: 18.909105
```

how can i debug the com.facebook.katana ?
Plz assit.
Rgds

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is apparently a bug --> http://bugs.developers.facebook.net/show_bug.cgi?id=16728              in the share intent for facebook and i doubt that's the reason it is not working .
Rgds,
Softy