# Sharing text in facebook with Android share intent

Tags: java, android, facebook, android-intent, facebook-android-sdk

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Android share intent for Facebook](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7076717/android-share-intent-for-facebook)

I'm trying share some text and a link in facebook with a share Intent in Android, but it don't works, this is my code

```
Intent sendIntent = new Intent();
sendIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
sendIntent.setType("text/plain");
sendIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, 
"some text here to share" + "https://maps.google.com/maps?saddr=-33.4429,+-70.6539");

startActivity(Intent.createChooser(sendIntent, getResources().getText(R.string.d_title)));
```

but just is shared the link, the text is missing... in twitter it works fine, but in facebook not. Help please :S thanks

Answer (score -3, accepted):

-- This answer has been changed --

According to the OP, this is not actually possible. He found a link (and he commented it down below) but here it is again: https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/332619626816423

Apparently prefilling a user's message is (or was at the time) disallowed due to the privacy policy.

Comment: thanks for your help, but this code works exactly like my code :/ it dont share the text in facebook

Comment: @HéctorCarrasco I added more to my answer at the bottom. Hopefully it helps.

Comment: thanks but the result is the same, I find this, https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/332619626816423 facebook API does not support pre-filling the message for users, for his privacy Policy

Comment: since this doesn't actually work .. why is it chosen as a correct answer ?