# Facebook not getting message from intent

Tags: android, facebook

I have used share inbuilt dialog of android.
Which fetch all application which is getting ACTION_SEND intent.
My code is

```
        Intent sharingIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
        sharingIntent.setType("text/plain");            
        sharingIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_TEXT,
                sharetext);
        startActivity(Intent.createChooser(sharingIntent, "Share"));
```

I am getting all apps like bluetooth, gmail, facebook, messaging, twitter, whatsapp in the list

All apps getting my message but not facebook.
What should i do to send message in facebook app. How it will detect my message.
Any help will be appreciated.
Thanks.

Comment: is facebook showing in the chooser? or is the problem related to facebook not taking in account your EXTRA_TEXT?

Comment: yes, facebook app shows in the chooser. but not getting message sent form my app. And i have accepted answers whenever i got the perfect answers. But unfortunately i dint receive and i dont accept fake answers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is a known bug and it's recorded on Facebook Platform Developers forum: http://forum.developers.facebook.net/viewtopic.php?id=93900

Apparently sharing text on facebook is possible on a few phones but it's still buggy on others: [Share Text on Facebook from Android App via ACTION_SEND](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3515198/share-text-on-facebook-from-android-app-via-action-send)

Comment: Thanks  for the help. May be i can see this to my client. so there is not my fault.

Comment: Alternatively you can use facebook sdk for android https://github.com/facebook/facebook-android-sdk.