# share using intent to facebook in android

Tags: android, facebook, android-intent

I use the following code to share content

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
intent.setType("text/plain");
intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "The status update text");
startActivity(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Dialog title text"));
```

It is OK for email, sms and whatever except **Facebook**.
I google the reason and it seems that it is a bug of facebook since April but unfortunately no one fixes it.

However, **I find that many app can still use intent chooser to invoke Facebook successfully such as Google reader. How can they do it?**

As I know, we can use Facebook API, but how they can know user choose facebook in the chooser and invoke the facebook API?

Comment: Check your facebook app version. and this [thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3515198/share-text-on-facebook-from-android-app-via-action-send)

Comment: I have the most updated version of facebook app...
As the thread you mentioned, I can just share link but not text... thx

Answer (score 7, accepted):

According to the latest updating to the bug tracker this is 'By Design' and the bug has been closed.
https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/332619626816423/

So looks like this isn't going to be possible via intents..

Comment: I am looking for the same answer and its still possible as I just did its testing in Pixlr Express.."https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.pixlr.express"

Answer (score 0):

You could only send pure URL to facebook. It should be a bug on facebook App.

For more detailed information, refer to the following post

[Share Text on Facebook from Android App via ACTION_SEND](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3515198/share-text-on-facebook-from-android-app-via-action-send)

---

Someone has posted this issue to official facebook bug tracker, but it's still not solved yet.

[Bug 16728 - Android ACTION_SEND is not handled correctly](http://bugs.developers.facebook.net/show_bug.cgi?id=16728)