# Intent Share Not Populating Facebook

Tags: android

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [share using intent to facebook in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8651249/share-using-intent-to-facebook-in-android)

I have an app which will send the data of a specifc string and some data that was captuerd via the app itself. The code below pops up a few options and then a few more depending on what apps you have installed on your phone.

All work fine except for Facebook when I try to share through this when it opens up the facebook app the box to type has nothing init. But when i try twitter, message, email etc..., they are all filled in with the correct information from the code.

**UPDATE**
After reading around I found this out to be a bug within the Facebook App, some people say this is fixed with the latest update of Facebook others say it isn't. Just have to wait and see what Facebook do.

```
private Intent createEmailIntent(String values) { 

           Intent emailIntent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND);
           emailIntent.setType("text/plain");
           emailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, getResources().getString(R.string.Subjecttwo));
           emailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, values);

           return emailIntent;
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

At the moment, Facebook app only supports text along with at least one URL. Make sure you have a URL in EXTRA_TEXT.

More here https://stackoverflow.com/a/4967008/54354

Answer (score 0):

Integrate the facebook sdk in your app to fill ..