# facebook share from android application

Tags: android

I am doing a android application.From my App I have to share a page when user clicks a button.So please provide me some sample code or suggest me some useful tutorial.Thanks in advance.

Comment: make your question little more clear and write things in proper way so that other can understand exactly what you want. And first try things yourself before asking any question  here as you can get many tutorials that can help you integrate facebook in android.

Answer (score 0):

This link here helps you to navigate to your default facebook app installed in your device.

[Share Text on Facebook from Android App via ACTION_SEND](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3515198/603744)

http://sudarmuthu.com/blog/sharing-content-in-android-using-action_send-intent