# Android:not getting proper text when sharing with inbuilt applications

Tags: android, android-intent, share

I used the following code.

```
 Intent share = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND);
    share.setType("text/plain");
    share.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, subject);
    share.putExtra(
            Intent.EXTRA_TEXT,
            "i have just visited http://www.google.com");
    startActivity(Intent.createChooser(share,
            "Share Sydneyho! with your friends via"));
```

When i select `gmail` its showing what is written in `Intent.EXTRA_TEXT` but when i am selecting `facebook` its entirely different message and i don't know from where its comes from.

please help!

Comment: what do you mean by "not getting proper text" ?

Comment: By proper text i mean to say its showing different message in different application.means when i select gmail its showing what is written in Intent.EXTRA_TEXT but when i am selecting facebook its entirely different message.

Comment: There are many similar question in here waiting for same answer [here is one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8706996/android-content-intent-action-send-facebook-does-not-receive-the-string)

Comment: thanks for answer not what i wanted but atleast someone given an answer good to see.

Comment: Here's a similar post for your reference. It looks like that you could only send a pure URL to facebook, but not mixing the text and URL. [Share Text on Facebook from Android App via ACTION_SEND](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3515198/share-text-on-facebook-from-android-app-via-action-send) ----------------------------- This issue has been fired to the official facebook bug list long time ago. But it still not solved. [Bug 16728 - Android ACTION_SEND is not handled correctly](http://bugs.developers.facebook.net/show_bug.cgi?id=16728)

Comment: thanks buddy i went through that post too but my requirement is to pass some text too.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Got some similar posts here at stackoverflow and come to this conclusion we cant pass text 
in

```
 share.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT,"bla bla bla");
```

to make it visible on facebook share page but we have to pass link to a website.

Answer (score 0):

I have used the following code snippet to share Message with Action_Send to other apps.

```
Intent sharingIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
sharingIntent.setType("text/plain");
sharingIntent.putExtra("android.intent.extra.SUBJECT", "");
sharingIntent.putExtra("android.intent.extra.TEXT", "ABC");
startActivity(Intent.createChooser(sharingIntent, "Share using"));
```

And it works fine in my device(Android 2.2).
Conceptually I dont know what is different between your code and above.
But the above code works fine for me.