# How to share data to social networking site from my application

Tags: android, facebook, data-sharing

In my application I want to share data to any of the social networking sites.

But problem is that whenever I share data on facebook I can't send text as well as image only display entry nothing else.

I am using:

```
sendIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
```

But the text which I am giving in Intents "putExtras()" is not being passed.

How can I do that?

Comment: means what u want to do ? wall post ?

Comment: See this post : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3515198/share-text-on-facebook-from-android-app-via-action-send

I think this will help.


Vikas

Comment: Then u have to integrate facebook sdk into your app.

Answer (score 0):

I have talked to some facebook people about that. They know it and yet they simply don't fix it. (I have seen a few other member from stackoverflow have the same experience)