# How to Share Url on facebook app allowing users to share it on facebook (on Web)

Tags: android, facebook, android-intent

In my app, i first implemented a facebook share button using Facebook URL to share the link i want. It appears on my wall and my friends can share it with other friends. All correct.

Now i have implemented ACTION_SEND intent with:

```
Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
i.setType("text/plain");
i.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, messageText + " " + mUrl + " vía @MyApp");
startActivity(Intent.createChooser(i, getString(R.string.select_app)));
```

With this code, link is posted on my facebook wall as status update, so it can be shared with anyone, only "like" and "comment".

Any solution for this? Maybe i have to use other mimetype? I cant found any solution on web...

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I've found similar question in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3515198/share-text-on-facebook-from-android-app-via-action-send , it seems to be a facebook api bug... any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

According to http://developers.facebook.com/bugs/332619626816423/ you cannot create prefilled posts. But... If your EXTRA_TEXT contains valid URL then facebook client finds the url and prepares it. All the user has to do is put in some words of his own.