# Share text to Social Media (Facebook/Twitter)

Tags: android

How can I share a text to a social medial site like facebook and twitter by clicking an imagebutton? I've seen one question here that also asks this kind of question but then I can't understand. This is my first app so I am hoping anyone here can help me with this. Thank you in advance.

P.S. Please don't be so rude answering questions. :)

Comment: Take a look [link](http://stackoverflow.com/a/24608685/4385913) and [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3515198/share-text-on-facebook-from-android-app-via-action-send)

Answer (score 6):

Try this:

## for facebook

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
intent .setType("text/plain");
intent .setPackage("com.facebook.katana");
intent .putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "Hello World");
try {
    activity.startActivity(intent );
} catch (android.content.ActivityNotFoundException ex) {
    ToastHelper.MakeShortText("Facebook have not been installed.");
}
```

## for twitter

```
Just change the package name to com.android.twitter
```

if you have facebook and twitter install on your device then it will direct share your text, else will show a toast of error.

Comment: Is there any needed package or permission or anything for this to work ?

Comment: only internet permission you have to declare in manifest, nothing else, give a try, and let me know if it works.

Comment: how can i declare permission?

Comment: in manifest file of your project under manifest tag and out of application tag.   <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

Answer (score 2):

If you want more than just Facebook and Twitter you can use the send intent.

So for the on click listener for the image button you could use this:

```
Intent shareIntent = new Intent();
shareIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "Text to share.");
shareIntent.setType("text/plain");
startActivity(shareIntent);
```

The benefit of this is that you can offer the user the ability to share on more than just Facebook and Twitter (any app they have installed that supports sharing of types "text/plain") and you don't have to check to see (or handle) certain apps being installed.

Comment: it doest post the score the player gets. Only the text the user inputed.