# Send Text and App name to Facebook

Tags: android, android-intent, facebook-android-sdk

Its share image and text in email and twitter but in facebook text is not displaying. `Is it possible to share text to facebook using intent?.`

Please help for this.

```
private void share(String nameApp, String imagePath) 
{
    try
    {
        List<Intent> targetedShareIntents = new ArrayList<Intent>();
        Intent share = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND);
        share.setType("image/jpeg");
        List<ResolveInfo> resInfo = getPackageManager().queryIntentActivities(share, 0);
        if (!resInfo.isEmpty()){
            for (ResolveInfo info : resInfo) {
                Intent targetedShare = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND);
                targetedShare.setType("image/jpeg"); // put here your mime type
                if (info.activityInfo.packageName.toLowerCase().contains(nameApp) || info.activityInfo.name.toLowerCase().contains(nameApp)) {
                    targetedShare.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "Virtual Mirror Photo");
                    targetedShare.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT,"This photo is created by Virtual Mirror App.\n\nInfoshore Team");
                    targetedShare.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, Uri.fromFile(new File(imagePath)) );
                    targetedShare.setPackage(info.activityInfo.packageName);
                    targetedShareIntents.add(targetedShare);
                }
            }
            Intent chooserIntent = Intent.createChooser(targetedShareIntents.remove(0), "Select app to share");
            chooserIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_INITIAL_INTENTS, targetedShareIntents.toArray(new Parcelable[]{}));
            startActivity(chooserIntent);
        }
    }
    catch(Exception e){
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per the Facebook's Platform Policies, We cannot pre-fill the share dialog using Intent.EXTRA_TEXT. It is usually thought to be a bug, but as per a Bug Report filed [here](https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/332619626816423/) and also, [here](https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/363863587019268), Facebook clearly mentions that this is not the case (it's not a bug).

I found that we cannot add a caption to a photo we are uploading using Intents. The only way we can do it, is integrating the **Facebook SDK** in your App then photo with text caption will be shared on facebook wall.

Answer (score 0):

yes its possible to share text using Facebook

```
Intent shareIntent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND);
shareIntent.setType("text/plain");
shareIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "Content to share");
PackageManager pm = v.getContext().getPackageManager();
List<ResolveInfo> activityList = pm.queryIntentActivities(shareIntent, 0);
for (final ResolveInfo app : activityList) {
    if ((app.activityInfo.name).contains("facebook")) {
        final ActivityInfo activity = app.activityInfo;
        final ComponentName name = new ComponentName(activity.applicationInfo.packageName, activity.name);
        shareIntent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER);
        shareIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK |             Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_RESET_TASK_IF_NEEDED);
        shareIntent.setComponent(name);
        v.getContext().startActivity(shareIntent);
        break;
   }
}
```

With the reference [StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3515198/share-text-on-facebook-from-android-app-via-action-send)

Comment: i want to share image with text. For sending image what should i modified in this above code..