# confused with android facebook sdk integration.Cannot work out

Tags: android, facebook, logout, facebook-login

I am facing problems in implementing facebook sdk 3.0 to my android app.I have read tons of tutorials and samples .But cannot work it out.
I have also read **documentation on facebook developers**.

But how should i **log out of facebook account** and **how to send a post to the facebook account which is login**.

I have setup the facebook sdk to my android app perfectly. I am facing problem with further code and steps.Can anyone share the code with me regarding **login**, **logout**, **sending a post to facebook account**.
I am stuck to this step for very very long time..

Any help will be appreciated.Thanks in advance.

Comment: what exactly you want to do?

Comment: Login on buttonClick,then post on wall by another buttonClick..

Comment: User should also be able to logout..

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if you had read and follow this tutorial but it is basically what you need for SDK3.0. It is well structured and easy to follow tutorial. 
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/getting-started/facebook-sdk-for-android/3.0/. Just a personal note, just don't skip any step and pay attention to Step 4. Run the Samples, where you need to create Key hash. Hope that helps.

Comment: yes,i have followed this tutorial .I am able to perform login to facebook. Then how to **send predefined post to facebook wall**

Comment: What do you mean "predefined post"? If you're looking for a complete example of posting status, image and etc, you could explore the complete examples that come with the SDK. HelloFacebookSample is a good example to start with.

Comment: i meant predefined text should be posted to the wall.Eg: text from the textview

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand you correctly. on line 306, Request.newStatusUpdateRequest(Session.getActiveSession(), message, new Request.Callback()..., you just have to change message to your textView.getText().toString().

Answer (score 0):

with thise line you can share with other apps installed on the device

```
Intent shareIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
shareIntent.setType("text/plain");
shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT,"body text");
```

those links may help you with the share.

[Share Text on Facebook from Android App via ACTION_SEND](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3515198/share-text-on-facebook-from-android-app-via-action-send)

http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/android/android-sdk-implement-a-share-intent/

Comment: I have to share only through facebook and also actions should to performed in background.