# Share button issue

Tags: android, eclipse, facebook, share

I'm working on an android app. It's about text convert. I added share button. It's working except facebook. When I click to share button and select facebook, the converted text doesn't seem in facebook share section. Here it's the share button code:

```
btn_share.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
                    Intent share = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
                    share.setType("text/plain");
                    share.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, text_converted);
                    share.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TITLE, "Cool Text Share");
                    startActivity(Intent.createChooser(share, "Cool Text Share"));
```

Comment: Facebook does not allow you to pre-set the text on shares, it's against policy. So any text you set will be ignored.

Comment: but most of the games and apps can share text. how can they do that?

Comment: For that, you have to request publish permissions from the user directly, and POST to me/feed using Graph API. Even then, you need to ask the user to type in the share text, otherwise it's still against policy and can get your app banned.

Comment: thanks a lot. everything solved in my mind ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
share.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, text_converted);
```

this code is waiting for `URL`

you may check this answer will help you alot : https://stackoverflow.com/a/4967008/1460591