# Android: How to share image with text on facebook via intent?

Tags: android, facebook, android-intent

I'd like to share a photo with caption pre-filled from my app via a share intent, on facebook.

Example code

```
Intent intent = new Intent();
intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
intent.setType("image/*");      

intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "eample");
intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TITLE, "example");
intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "example");
intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, imageUri);

Intent openInChooser = new Intent(intent);
openInChooser.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_INITIAL_INTENTS, extraIntents);
startActivity(openInChooser);
```

Here is screen shot what I get

[image: Text is not display]

If a set type to image/* then a photo is uploaded without the text prefilled. If a set it to text/plain photo is not display.....

Comment: once check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20015410/customize-android-intent-action-send/20015435#20015435

Comment: I think you use facebook Api..

Comment: i think you should use facebookSdk for this

Comment: possible duplicate of [Facebook post not showing](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23782639/facebook-post-not-showing)

Comment: chekc this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33951442/how-to-share-image-using-facebook-android

Answer (score 47, accepted):

The newest Facebook versions doesn't allow you to share text using intents. You have to use the Facebook SDK to do it - to make that simple, use the Facebook SDK + Android Simple Facebook (https://github.com/sromku/android-simple-facebook). Using the library, your code would be like this (extracted from the Simple Facebook site):

### Publish feed

Set `OnPublishListener` and call for:

- `publish(Feed, OnPublishListener)` without dialog.
- `publish(Feed, true, OnPublishListener)` with dialog.

#### Basic properties

- `message` - The message of the user
- `name` - The name of the link attachment
- `caption` - The caption of the link (appears beneath the link name)
- `description` - The description of the link (appears beneath the link caption)
- `picture` - The URL of a picture attached to this post. The picture must be at least 200px by 200px
- `link` - The link attached to this post

Initialize callback listener:

```
OnPublishListener onPublishListener = new OnPublishListener() {
    @Override
        public void onComplete(String postId) {
            Log.i(TAG, "Published successfully. The new post id = " + postId);
        }

     /* 
      * You can override other methods here: 
      * onThinking(), onFail(String reason), onException(Throwable throwable)
      */
};
```

Build feed:

```
Feed feed = new Feed.Builder()
    .setMessage("Clone it out...")
    .setName("Simple Facebook for Android")
    .setCaption("Code less, do the same.")
    .setDescription("The Simple Facebook library project makes the life much easier by coding less code for being able to login, publish feeds and open graph stories, invite friends and more.")
    .setPicture("https://raw.github.com/sromku/android-simple-facebook/master/Refs/android_facebook_sdk_logo.png")
    .setLink("https://github.com/sromku/android-simple-facebook")
    .build();
```

Publish feed **without** dialog:

```
mSimpleFacebook.publish(feed, onPublishListener);
```

Publish feed **with** dialog:

```
mSimpleFacebook.publish(feed, true, onPublishListener);
```

### Update on 14 December 2015

according to New Facebook SDK.

> facebook-android-sdk:4.6.0

It's very Simple.

**1. create Provider in `Android.manifest.xml`**

```
<provider
            android:authorities="com.facebook.app.FacebookContentProvider{APP_ID}"
            android:name="com.facebook.FacebookContentProvider"
            android:exported="true" />
```

**2. Create Your Share Intent with Data.**

```
ShareHashtag shareHashTag = new ShareHashtag.Builder().setHashtag("#YOUR_HASHTAG").build();
ShareLinkContent shareLinkContent = new ShareLinkContent.Builder()
                .setShareHashtag(shareHashTag)
                .setQuote("Your Description")
                .setContentUrl(Uri.parse("image or logo [if playstore or app store url then no need of this image url]"))
                .build();
```

**3. Show The Share Dialog**

```
ShareDialog.show(ShowNavigationActivity.this,shareLinkContent);
```

That's It.

Comment: is this library still working with new policies and FB SDK version? after I press login in you sample i get error to login the app. Can you help me? thanks

Comment: I think it's ironic that the Facebook *SDK* requires a "simple facebook" library. I can't get over it I'm going to bust my gut laughing out loud.

Comment: The only issue for me is that I can't see the posted picture in my Facebook website. But I can see it in my mobile Facebook application. Why?

Comment: re comment about irony (I agree): I guess it's about 'lock-in', ie facebook wants you to share via them but not share via anyone else

Comment: what is mSimpleFacebook ? how can I initialize it ?

Comment: It does not work. Always got "user canceled the permissions dialog".

Comment: It IS allowed to image and text on fb without their SDK

Comment: `setContentTitle("title")` and `setContentDescription("description")` is now deprectaed. now what to use to set title and description.

Comment: facebook-android-sdk:4.6.0 work well with 5.2.0 well done

Answer (score 4):

As of 2017, facebook doesn't allow sharing of an image + text together, directly from your app.

## Workaround

Facebook will though, scrape a URL for title and image data and will use that in a share post.

As a workaround you could create a single page application* that dynamically loads the text/image you want to share (specified in the URL) and you can facebook-share that URL.

Notes:

- Ensure your single page application produces a static page which has its title, open graph meta tags, and images set prior to facebook's page scrape.  If these web page tags are changed dynamically through Javascript, facebook will not be able to scrape those values and use them in its share post.
- Use open graph meta property tags og:image:height and og:image:width to allow [facebook to create an image preview](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/best-practices#images) within its share post

## Steps

0) add the [latest facebook-sdk library](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.facebook.android/facebook-android-sdk) to your build.gradle file

```
compile group: 'com.facebook.android', name: 'facebook-android-sdk', version: '4.25.0'
```

1) In your AndroidManifest.xml, add a meta-data tag within your `<application>` section:

```
<application android:label="@string/app_name" ...>
...
    <meta-data android:name="com.facebook.sdk.ApplicationId" android:value="@string/facebook_app_id"/>
...
</application>
```

Add a facebook_app_id string (with your APP ID) to your strings.xml file:

```
<string name="facebook_app_id">12341234</string>
```

YOURFBAPPID is your Facebook App ID number found at https://developers.facebook.com/apps/

2) also add a `<provider>` tag outside of your `<application>` tag in AndroidManifest.xml

```
<provider android:authorities="com.facebook.app.FacebookContentProviderYOURFBAPPID"
          android:name="com.facebook.FacebookContentProvider"
          android:exported="true"/>
```

3) Create a ShareLinkContent object using their builder:

```
ShareLinkContent fbShare = new ShareLinkContent.Builder()
            .setContentUrl(Uri.parse("http://yourdomain.com/your-title-here/someimagefilename"))
            .build();
```

4) Share it from your fragment (or activity, etc.):

```
ShareDialog.show(getActivity(), fbShare);
```

---

### Facebook Docs

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/android/getting-started

Answer (score 2):

FB no longer allows you to prefill the sharing message.

In order to circumvent this, you will need to use an SDK to publish via a Graph request. For this you will need the `publish_actions` permission. Since last month you need to [submit your app to a review process](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/permissions/v2.2) to gain access to `publish_actions`. Which you would fail if your app prefills the sharing texts. Trust me - I've had the Chutzppah to try.

So it looks like we would have to comply.

B.t.w. in iOS you can still prefill the texts using the FB sdk. Who knows for how long.

Comment: then how did you pre-fills since there is no option?

Answer (score 1):

In this Formula you can share image both Messenger and Instagram(com.instagram.android) without using any Provider in "AndroidManifest

```
public void shareMessenger(View v) {
    // showToast("checking");

    File dir = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), "MyFolder");

    File imgFile = new File(dir, "Image.png");

    Intent sendIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
    sendIntent.setType("image/*");
    sendIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
    sendIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, Uri.parse("file://" + imgFile));
    sendIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "<---MY TEXT--->.");
    sendIntent.setPackage("com.facebook.orca");
    sendIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
    try {
        startActivity(Intent.createChooser(sendIntent, "Share images..."));
    } catch (android.content.ActivityNotFoundException ex) {
        Toast.makeText(SaveAndShareActivity.this, "Please Install Facebook Messenger", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }

}
```

**Add this two line in onCreate Method **

```
 StrictMode.VmPolicy.Builder builder = new StrictMode.VmPolicy.Builder();
    StrictMode.setVmPolicy(builder.build());
```

Comment: Hello Khairun :) Please make sure to format your code properly and not leave anything out. If you are dividing code into sections please make it clear what they mean.

Answer (score -1):

Add these lines to your following code

```
shareCaptionIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TITLE, "my awesome caption in the EXTRA_TITLE field");
```

Answer (score -1):

Without using Facebook sdk we can't share the image and text simultaneously on facebook. To solve this problem I had create a bitmap of image and text, Share that bitmap on facebook and it's working perfectly.

You can download the source code from here ([Share image and text on facebook using intent in android](https://deepshikhapuri.wordpress.com/2016/12/12/share-image-and-text-on-facebook-using-intent-in-android/))

Here is code:

**MainActivity.java**

```
package com.shareimage;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.text.Editable;
import android.text.TextWatcher;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.RelativeLayout;
import android.widget.TextView;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements 
View.OnClickListener {
EditText et_text;
ImageView iv_image;
TextView tv_share,tv_text;
RelativeLayout rl_main;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    init();

}

private void init(){
    et_text = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.et_text);
    iv_image = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.iv_image);
    tv_share = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.tv_share);
    rl_main = (RelativeLayout)findViewById(R.id.rl_main);
    tv_text= (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv_text);

    File dir = new File("/sdcard/Testing/");
    try {
        if (dir.mkdir()) {
            System.out.println("Directory created");
        } else {
            System.out.println("Directory is not created");
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    tv_share.setOnClickListener(this);

    et_text.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {

        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
            tv_text.setText(et_text.getText().toString());

        }
    });


}




@Override
public void onClick(View v) {

    switch (v.getId()){
        case R.id.tv_share:
            Bitmap bitmap1 = loadBitmapFromView(rl_main, rl_main.getWidth(), rl_main.getHeight());
            saveBitmap(bitmap1);
            String str_screenshot = "/sdcard/Testing/"+"testing" + ".jpg";

            fn_share(str_screenshot);
            break;
    }

}

public void saveBitmap(Bitmap bitmap) {
    File imagePath = new File("/sdcard/Testing/"+"testing" + ".jpg");
    FileOutputStream fos;
    try {
        fos = new FileOutputStream(imagePath);
        bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, fos);
        fos.flush();
        fos.close();

        Log.e("ImageSave", "Saveimage");
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        Log.e("GREC", e.getMessage(), e);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        Log.e("GREC", e.getMessage(), e);
    }
}

public static Bitmap loadBitmapFromView(View v, int width, int height) {
    Bitmap b = Bitmap.createBitmap(width, height, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
    Canvas c = new Canvas(b);
    v.draw(c);

    return b;
}

public void fn_share(String path) {

    File file = new File("/mnt/" + path);

    Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(file.getAbsolutePath());
    Uri uri = Uri.fromFile(file);
    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
    intent.setType("image/*");
    intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, uri);

    startActivity(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Share Image"));


}

}
```

Answer (score -3):

```
Intent shareIntent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND);

   shareIntent.setType("image/*");

   shareIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, (String) v.getTag(R.string.app_name));

   shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, imageUri); // put your image URI

   PackageManager pm = v.getContext().getPackageManager();

   List<ResolveInfo> activityList = pm.queryIntentActivities(shareIntent, 0);

     for (final ResolveInfo app : activityList) 
     {
         if ((app.activityInfo.name).contains("facebook")) 
         {

           final ActivityInfo activity = app.activityInfo;

           final ComponentName name = new ComponentName(activity.applicationInfo.packageName, activity.name);

          shareIntent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER);

          shareIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_RESET_TASK_IF_NEEDED);

          shareIntent.setComponent(name);

          v.getContext().startActivity(shareIntent);

          break;
        }
      }
```

Comment: Can you explain your solution?

Comment: when u want to share text via facebook only then when ll u tapping on share button it ll fire startactivity and check it every time that packagename of installed application , and when it`ll get facebook`s package name then rest of the code is to being execute and text is shared

Comment: intents with `.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER)` don't work - just launches the main FB on the timeline and not the UI to post a new item