# Facebook post not showing

Tags: android, facebook

I created a app in facebook developers site and used the appId in my app and try to post in facebook, when i logged using the same fb account in my app and posted using my facebook, it posts successfully , but when i tried  login with a different account its not posting...can any body help....

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.facebook.FacebookRequestError;
import com.facebook.HttpMethod;
import com.facebook.Request;
import com.facebook.RequestAsyncTask;
import com.facebook.Response;
import com.facebook.Session;
import com.facebook.SessionLoginBehavior;
import com.facebook.SessionState;
import com.suppliers.bee2buy.R;
import com.suppliers.utils.AppPreferences;

public class ShareData extends Activity {
    private Session.StatusCallback sessionStatusCallback;
    private Session currentSession;
    Button publishButton;
    AppPreferences appPref;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.sharedata);
        appPref = new AppPreferences(ShareData.this, "PREFS");
        publishButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.publishButton);

        connectToFB();

        publishButton.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

        // create instace for sessionStatusCallback
        sessionStatusCallback = new Session.StatusCallback() {

            @Override
            public void call(Session session, SessionState state,
                    Exception exception) {
                onSessionStateChange(session, state, exception);

            }
        };

        // logout button

        // publish button
        publishButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.publishButton);
        publishButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                publishStorys();

            }
        });

    }

    /**
     * Connects the user to facebook
     */
    public void connectToFB() {

        List<String> permissions = new ArrayList<String>();
        permissions.add("publish_stream");


        currentSession = new Session.Builder(this).build();
        currentSession.addCallback(sessionStatusCallback);

        Session.OpenRequest openRequest = new Session.OpenRequest(
                ShareData.this);
        openRequest.setLoginBehavior(SessionLoginBehavior.SUPPRESS_SSO);
        openRequest.setRequestCode(Session.DEFAULT_AUTHORIZE_ACTIVITY_CODE);
        openRequest.setPermissions(permissions);
        currentSession.openForPublish(openRequest);

    }

    /**
     * this method is used by the facebook API
     */
    @Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        if (currentSession != null) {
            currentSession
                    .onActivityResult(this, requestCode, resultCode, data);
        }
    }

    /**
     * manages the session state change. This method is called after the
     * <code>connectToFB</code> method.
     * 
     * @param session
     * @param state
     * @param exception
     */
    private void onSessionStateChange(Session session, SessionState state,
            Exception exception) {
        if (session != currentSession) {
            return;
        }

        if (state.isOpened()) {
            // Log in just happened.
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "session opened",
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        } else if (state.isClosed()) {
            // Log out just happened. Update the UI.
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "session closed",
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }

    /**
     * Publishes story on the logged user's wall
     */

    private void publishStorys() {
        if (currentSession != null) {
            // this is not used
            // Bitmap icon =
            // BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getApplicationContext()
            // .getResources(), R.drawable.ic_launcher);

            Bundle postParams = new Bundle();
            postParams.putString("name", "Product Shared from Bee2Buy");
            postParams.putString("caption", appPref.getData("share_title"));
            // postParams
            // .putString(
            // "description",
            // "The Facebook SDK for Android makes it easier and faster to develop Facebook integrated Android apps.");
            postParams.putString(
                    "link",
                    "http://www.saznaitsols.com/site_uploads/product/"
                            + appPref.getData("share_img"));
            postParams.putString(
                    "picture",
                    "http://www.saznaitsols.com/site_uploads/product/"
                            + appPref.getData("share_img"));

            Request.Callback callback = new Request.Callback() {
                public void onCompleted(Response response) {

                    FacebookRequestError error = response.getError();
                    if (error != null) {
                        Toast.makeText(ShareData.this.getApplicationContext(),
                                error.getErrorMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                                .show();
                    } else {
                        // Toast.makeText(
                        // ShareData.this.getApplicationContext(),
                        // postId, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                }
            };

            Request request = new Request(currentSession, "me/feed",
                    postParams, HttpMethod.POST, callback);

            RequestAsyncTask task = new RequestAsyncTask(request);
            task.execute();
            Toast.makeText(ShareData.this, "Posted on fb", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            ShareData.this.finish();


        } else {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Error", Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                    .show();
        }

    }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks Tobi for your reply.. i have found another solution to share data on facebook, using the feed dialog now recommended by facebook team, if you are ok with an extra dialog of what you post on facebook, we can use this method. But be sure we have given all the permission like Tobi said..

```
   private void publishFeedDialog() {
            Bundle params = new Bundle();
            params.putString("name", "Product shared from Bee2buy");
            params.putString("caption",
                    appPref.getData("share_title"));

            params.putString("link", "http://www.saznaitsols.com/site_uploads/product/"
                    + appPref.getData("share_img"));
            params.putString("picture",
                    "http://www.saznaitsols.com/site_uploads/product/"
                            + appPref.getData("share_img"));

            WebDialog feedDialog = (new WebDialog.FeedDialogBuilder(
                    ShareData.this, currentSession, params))
                    .setOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener() {

                        @Override
                        public void onComplete(Bundle values,
                                FacebookException error) {
                            if (error == null) {
                                // When the story is posted, echo the success
                                // and the post Id.
                                final String postId = values.getString("post_id");
                                if (postId != null) {
                                    Toast.makeText(ShareData.this,
                                            "Posted story, id: " + postId,
                                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                } else {
                                    // User clicked the Cancel button
                                    Toast.makeText(
                                            ShareData.this
                                                    .getApplicationContext(),
                                            "Publish cancelled", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                                            .show();
                                }
                            } else if (error instanceof FacebookOperationCanceledException) {
                                // User clicked the "x" button
                                Toast.makeText(
                                        ShareData.this.getApplicationContext(),
                                        "Publish cancelled", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                                        .show();
                            } else {
                                // Generic, ex: network error
                                Toast.makeText(
                                        ShareData.this.getApplicationContext(),
                                        "Error posting story", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                                        .show();
                            }
                        }



                    }).build();
            feedDialog.show();
        }
```

Answer (score 2):

You should request the `publish_actions` permission according to https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.0/user/feed/#publish when you want to post something to a User's wall.

If you use a diffrent account, do you see the permission dialog? I suspect the first User you're trying it with is the admin of your app, whereas the second isn't. That's why it works for the first one.

Comment: the above method has some problem it was working fine with older SDK's but with newer ones its not working!! atleast for me its not working