# is "publish_action" permission necessary to post on facebook wall through android applicaton?

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-opengraph, facebook-android-sdk

I just need to post some text and Image on the Facebook wall of my app's user.
The Facebook app registered in developers.facebook.com doesn't have "publish_actions" permission by default. I already have submitted request for this permission but its taking long to get approved. 
Meanwhile seeing my friend doing this post operation thorugh ios app without this "publish_action" permission I am curious do i need this permission to post some text and image on users wall at all? Please help me..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You dont, if you are using open graph:

Reference: [The Share dialog lets people publish stories from your app without Facebook Login or the publish_actions permission](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/opengraph/android). However you still have to send your app for review.

The best part is that a user can tag people in a post built upon graph API. As a sample app I would suggest you check how Scrumptious works, it comes prepackaged in the FB SDK.

Comment: Thank you .. wasn't aware of this simple way

Comment: Can relate, the documentation is half assed

Answer (score 0):

You can check this link: [Android: How to share image with text on facebook via intent?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22533773/android-how-to-share-image-with-text-on-facebook-via-intent)

Use intent sharing for normal text and image post

Answer (score 0):

> **Publishing**
>
> You can publish posts by using the /{user-id}/feed, /{page-id}/feed,
>   /{event-id}/feed, or /{group-id}/feed edges.
>
> When creating a Post for a Page if you use a user access token the
>   post will be in the voice of the user that posted it. If you use a
>   page access token, the post will be in the voice of the page.

[Source](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.3/post).

> **Upload Photos to a User's Profile**
>
> This example covers uploading a photo to the current User's profile
>   using the Graph API and the Facebook SDK for PHP.
>
> It assumes that you've already set your default app id and secret, and
>   acquired a FacebookSession using an access token or one of the login
>   helper classes found here. **You must have requested the publish_actions**
>   **scope when logging in the user for this to work**.
>
> For more information, see the documentation for GraphObject,
>   FacebookRequest, and FacebookRequestException.

[Source](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/php/howto/uploadphoto/4.0.0).

As you can see, you need the publish_actions privilege to post to wall a post with picture and text. You need a review as well.