# share Image and text in Android

Tags: android, image, text, share-intent

I'm using the code below to share Image and text in Android. When I choose Whatsapp it shares the image and text together , but when I choose Facebook it just shares Image without any text! What's mistake in my code? Thanks.

```
Intent share = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
share.setType("image/jpeg");
share.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, Uri.fromFile(new File(bitmapPath)));
share.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "Shared via" +  APP_URL);
startActivity(Intent.createChooser(share, "Share Image"));
```

Comment: U need to reply to the answers given, or accept one!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**`Facebook will not allow you to Share any static text you want.`**

`That's why Facebook have provide it's own Share Dialog to post any text on facebook.`

`It will take image as static but not text.`

**`So better for facebook share only you use Facebook Share Dialog.`**

`The thing is, if you put a URL in the EXTRA_TEXT field, it does work. It's   like they're intentionally stripping out any text.`

**`**Check below links for Integration of Facebook Share.**`**

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/reference/share-dialog

[Android: How to share image with text on facebook via intent?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22533773/android-how-to-share-image-with-text-on-facebook-via-intent)

Answer (score 2):

> What's wrong in my code?

Probably nothing. [`ACTION_SEND`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#ACTION_SEND) supports *either* `EXTRA_TEXT` *or* `EXTRA_STREAM` in one `Intent`, not both ("...can have either a EXTRA_TEXT or EXTRA_STREAM field, containing the data to be sent"). Some `ACTION_SEND` implementations will go beyond the documented protocol and try to use both. Others will stick with the documented protocol and only use one. In this case, Facebook perhaps chose to stick with the documented protocol and only use one.

Answer (score 0):

Facebook changed their policy so you cannot share both the image and text. It's no longer possible what so ever

Answer (score 0):

> You cannot share text with Facebook anymore! **Period**.

Answer (score 0):

Its not possible to share the image and text together on facebook using intent. But if you want to share both then you have to create the bitmap of image and text.

Download the source code from here([Share image and text on facebook using intent in android](https://deepshikhapuri.wordpress.com/2016/12/12/share-image-and-text-on-facebook-using-intent-in-android/))

**activity_main.xml:**

```
<RelativeLayout android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#ffffff"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/et_text"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:textSize="15dp"
        android:layout_height="45dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:background="@drawable/edittext_drawable"
        android:hint="Enter your text"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:paddingRight="10dp"
        android:inputType="text"
        android:imeOptions="actionDone"
        android:paddingLeft="10dp"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:textColorHint="#979797" />


    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/rl_main"
        android:background="#ffffff"
        android:layout_below="@+id/et_text"
        android:layout_above="@+id/tv_share">


        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="250dp"
            android:src="@drawable/index"
            android:scaleType="fitXY"
            android:id="@+id/iv_image"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textSize="15dp"
            android:id="@+id/tv_text"
            android:layout_below="@+id/iv_image"
            android:layout_margin="10dp"
            android:textColor="#000000"
            android:maxLines="5"
            />

    </RelativeLayout>



    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv_share"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:background="#F38D0A"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:layout_margin="10dp"
        android:text="Share"
        android:textColor="#ffffff"
        android:textSize="15dp"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"/>

    </RelativeLayout>
```

**MainActivity.java**

package com.shareimage;

```
import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.text.Editable;
import android.text.TextWatcher;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.RelativeLayout;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {
    EditText et_text;
    ImageView iv_image;
    TextView tv_share,tv_text;
    RelativeLayout rl_main;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        init();

    }

    private void init(){
        et_text = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.et_text);
        iv_image = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.iv_image);
        tv_share = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.tv_share);
        rl_main = (RelativeLayout)findViewById(R.id.rl_main);
        tv_text= (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv_text);

        File dir = new File("/sdcard/Testing/");
        try {
            if (dir.mkdir()) {
                System.out.println("Directory created");
            } else {
                System.out.println("Directory is not created");
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        tv_share.setOnClickListener(this);

        et_text.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {

            }

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
                tv_text.setText(et_text.getText().toString());

            }
        });


    }




    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

        switch (v.getId()){
            case R.id.tv_share:
                Bitmap bitmap1 = loadBitmapFromView(rl_main, rl_main.getWidth(), rl_main.getHeight());
                saveBitmap(bitmap1);
                String str_screenshot = "/sdcard/Testing/"+"testing" + ".jpg";

                fn_share(str_screenshot);
                break;
        }

    }

    public void saveBitmap(Bitmap bitmap) {
        File imagePath = new File("/sdcard/Testing/"+"testing" + ".jpg");
        FileOutputStream fos;
        try {
            fos = new FileOutputStream(imagePath);
            bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, fos);
            fos.flush();
            fos.close();

            Log.e("ImageSave", "Saveimage");
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            Log.e("GREC", e.getMessage(), e);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e("GREC", e.getMessage(), e);
        }
    }

    public static Bitmap loadBitmapFromView(View v, int width, int height) {
        Bitmap b = Bitmap.createBitmap(width, height, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
        Canvas c = new Canvas(b);
        v.draw(c);

        return b;
    }

    public void fn_share(String path) {

        File file = new File("/mnt/" + path);

        Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(file.getAbsolutePath());
        Uri uri = Uri.fromFile(file);
        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
        intent.setType("image/*");
        intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, uri);

        startActivity(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Share Image"));


    }
}
```

Thanks!