# Display editable text in Facebook Share Dialog

Tags: android, android-facebook, facebook-sdk-4.x

I am using the Facebook SDK to create a sharedialog with a sharecontent. However, how should i display editable text in the share dialog. I'm able to show links and all. I just don't know how to set a custom text which the user can edit.

```
ShareLinkContent content = new ShareLinkContent.Builder()
                                .setContentTitle("App Name")
                                .setContentDescription("Hi!! This is app")
                                .setContentUrl(Uri.parse("http://www.fsdfvdsf.com"))
                                .build();

                        shareDialog.show(content);
```

Answer (score 0):

Facebook sdk does not allow you to add editable text

Answer (score 0):

> Don't prefill captions, comments, messages, or the user message parameter of posts with content a person didn’t create, even if the person can edit or remove the content before sharing. You may use our Share Dialogs to prefill a single hashtag in a post, but don't prefill any content a person didn't create via the API.

Reference: https://developers.facebook.com/policy/

Comment: If we some how able to do so, the fb review team'll not allow us to submit this.

Answer (score 0):

**`Facebook will not allow you to Share any static text you want.`**

`That's why Facebook have provide it's own Share Dialog to post any text on facebook.`

`It will take image **OR** URL as static but not text.`

**`So better for Facebook share only you use Facebook Share Dialog.`**

`The thing is, if you put a URL in the EXTRA_TEXT field, it does work. It's   like they're intentionally stripping out any text.`

For **`Share Feed`** check [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22533773/android-how-to-share-image-with-text-on-facebook-via-intent).