# Sharing image to facebook wall from sd card by normal way and also by Facebook SDK

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-android-sdk

i want to share image to my facebook wall, for that i am taking the image from sd card and then sharing, 
my code :

```
String dirpath = android.os.Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString();
String path = dirpath+"/test.png";
Uri imageUri = Uri.parse(path);

Intent sharingIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
sharingIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
sharingIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, imageUri);
sharingIntent.setType("image/png");
startActivity(Intent.createChooser(sharingIntent , "Send image using.."));
```

but its not working, please give me some solution.

Also i want code for sharing image using Facebook SDK..

Comment: Check out my answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/20015435/1839336

Answer (score 3):

```
protected void share(String nameApp, String imagePath, String text) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        try {
            List<Intent> targetedShareIntents = new ArrayList<Intent>();
            Intent share = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND);
            share.setType("image/jpeg");
            List<ResolveInfo> resInfo = getPackageManager()
                    .queryIntentActivities(share, 0);
            if (!resInfo.isEmpty()) {
                for (ResolveInfo info : resInfo) {
                    Intent targetedShare = new Intent(
                            android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND);
                    targetedShare.setType("image/jpeg"); // put here your mime
                    // type
                    if (info.activityInfo.packageName.toLowerCase().contains(
                            nameApp)
                            || info.activityInfo.name.toLowerCase().contains(
                                    nameApp)) {
                        targetedShare.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, text);
                        targetedShare.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, text);
                        targetedShare.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM,
                                Uri.fromFile(new File(imagePath)));
                        targetedShare.setPackage(info.activityInfo.packageName);
                        targetedShareIntents.add(targetedShare);
                    }
                }
                Intent chooserIntent = Intent.createChooser(
                        targetedShareIntents.remove(0), "Select app to share");
                chooserIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_INITIAL_INTENTS,
                        targetedShareIntents.toArray(new Parcelable[] {}));
                startActivity(chooserIntent);
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
        }

    }
```

Comment: Hey it worked for me, thanx @sam
Can you give me any example for sharing the image using Facebook SDK?

Answer (score 1):

> **It Was My Problem Too**

you used

```
Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK
```

so it means you are not in activity

And Your Error Is:

> android.util.AndroidRuntimeException: Calling startActivity() from outside of an Activity  context requires the FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK flag. Is this really what you want?

you should make Global Class
so what's that?

create class for example its name is G.java

public class G extends Application {
}

extends application

and Define it in "**AndroidManifest.xml**"

```
    <application
    android:name=".G"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name" >
```

And Create :

```
public static Activity              currentActivity;
```

"**currentActivity**" is Variable save your Current Activity

in onResume Event of your activity write:

```
    G.currentActivity = this;
    super.onResume();
```

**Attention:** it must place before
        super.onresume();

So in your code use:

```
                    G.currentActivity.startActivity(Intent.createChooser(sharingIntent, "Share via..."));


    G.currentActivity.
```

used before :

```
    startActivity(Intent);
```