# Share image from URL via Twitter app - Android

Tags: android, android-intent, twitter, uri, android-sharing

I'm trying to share some text and image via the Twitter app. The image source is a web url. 
Below is my code:

```
sharingIntent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND);    
sharingIntent.setType("*/*");    
sharingIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "I am reading this publication, check it out here: "+bookmark_url+"");
sharingIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, Uri.parse("http://example.com/images/thumbs/file_name.jpg"));
```

But only the text is getting shared via the Twitter app. I also get a message saying "**Image could not be loaded**". What is the problem with this code?

Comment: Please let me know if there is any work around

Comment: Hope the followign link can help you. [link][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20015410/customize-android-intent-action-send

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Sourav, I think you must download the picture before sharing it. You can do it [manually](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15549639/2528167), or maybe you could use a library like [this](https://github.com/nostra13/Android-Universal-Image-Loader). You can find inside the library's repository easy documentation about how to set up and use it.

After you have downloaded the picture you can follow this method:

```
private Intent shareIntent(String bookmark_url, String imagePath){
    sharingIntent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND);    
    sharingIntent.setType("*/*");    
    sharingIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "I am reading this publication, check it out here: "+bookmark_url);
    sharingIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, Uri.fromFile(new File(imagePath)));
    return sharingIntent;
}
```

If you simply want to simulate "Parsing image on the fly", delete it after sharing.

Hope this helps you!

Comment: I have some constraints in terms of storage on the SD card....can u confirm that sharing the image directly from the URL is not possible in Twitter?

Comment: I have seen that happening on other platforms like iOS

Comment: @Sourav I cannot confirm that is not possible to share the image directly from the URL but I am pretty sure due to two reasons: 1º your error is quite clear: "Image could not be loaded", 2º I have worked with Twitter API for PHP and I had to download pictures before send a tweet with them because if I didn't do that I obtained text tweets without pictures like you.