# ACTION_SEND: Possible to filter applications which accept attachments?

Tags: android, android-intent, attachment

I am trying to share text and attachment using `ACTION_SEND`.

```
    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
    intent.setType("text/plain");
    intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, new String[]{"email"});
    intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "subject");
    intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "body");

    Uri uri = Uri.fromFile(file);
    intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, uri);

    startActivity(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Send..."));
```

However, in the list appear applications like Hangouts which do not accept attachments.

Can I filter out application which do not accept attachments? Is there a tag or another indicator which can tell me if application accepts attachments or not?

Comment: Check : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20015410/customize-android-intent-action-send

Comment: @HareshChhelana This is package filtering which is really unreliable. I already found this post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
  intent.setType("message/rfc822");
```

Use this.