# How to implement sharing text option for android and ios using Delphi

Tags: android, ios, facebook, delphi, delphi-10.1-berlin

I'm using Delphi 10.1.2 Berlin for developing android and iOs mobile application. And I have faced  [issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41670287/sharing-functionality-issue-for-facebook-app-using-delphi-10-1-berlin) for Facebook text sharing option.

And how can I able to implement Facebook text sharing option using SDK?
And I don't find any clear help files for sharing text in FB using Delphi.
Please help me and Thanks in advance.

Comment: There is no way. You are not allowed to prefill text

Comment: But they have mentioned the [Facebook sharing option](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/android) using Java. But the example is not provided for Delphi

Comment: Where in that document do they mention text sharing?

Comment: **a contentDescription of the content, usually 2-4 sentences** is the place where we can provide the text

Comment: Sure. https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.8/user/feed#publish explains how you specify description of the link

Comment: But How can I implement this in Delphi.?

Comment: I have no idea how you do an HTTP request in Delphi but I assume the are guides that tell you how to do that. And then you read the Facebook documentation on what you need to send to Facebook

Answer (score 3):

Here is multiplatform version:

```
uses   
  FMX.Platform, FMX.MediaLibrary;  

procedure ShareTextWith(const aText: string);
var
  vSharingService: IFMXShareSheetActionsService;
begin
  TPlatformServices.Current.SupportsPlatformService(IFMXShareSheetActionsService, vSharingService);
  vSharingService.Share(nil, aText, nil);

end;
```

Also you can use [ShowShareSheetAction](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Tokyo/en/Taking_and_Sharing_Pictures_and_Text_Using_Action_Lists) for both platform.

Comment: this work on android too so you can remove `{$IFDEF iOS}`