# How to set condition for setType in share intent?

Tags: android, android-intent

I am stuck in very small problem in share intent, while i am sharing both text and image to other apps by setting  "**intent.setType("text/plain")**" its working perfectly in all google apps(Google+,Hangout,Gmail etc) and when i select Facebook from apps list then url is appearing in Facebook timeline which also works good but INSTAGRAM app not appearing in all apps list but when i change "**intent.setType("text/plain")**" to  "**intent.setType("image/*")**" then INSTAGRAM appear but then facebook app only shows image in timeline not url.
So how can i apply check to package resolver so that all apps should appear in share intent dialog and link should appear in facebook timeline on selecting Facebook App and image should appear in instagram app while we select INSTAGRAM app.
Any help will be appriciated

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6814268/android-share-on-facebook-twitter-mail-ecc

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20015410/customize-android-intent-action-send

Comment: @IntelliJAmiya links you mentioned are for different scenario , i want to filter condition **setType** for instagram app so that instagram app will appear in popup and am able to share image via instagram.