# sharing to facebook from android intent issue

Tags: java, android, facebook, android-intent

while i have successfully shared strings to other apps like email.. there's a problem with facebook...

here's my code:

```
 private void sharePost() {

Intent shareIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, dataSecContent);
shareIntent.setType("text/plain");
startActivity(Intent.createChooser(shareIntent,
        getString(R.string.share_chooser_title)));
 }
```

this is what i only get... no strings or whatsoever...

[image: facebook share]

what am i doing wrong? i've tried sending URLs with uri and it successfully shared.. but not strings..

Comment: possible duplicates http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3515198/share-text-on-facebook-from-android-app-via-action-send and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7545254/android-and-facebook-share-intent?rq=1 still not solved

Comment: @zipc yeah its the same.. i have just checked them out... there's a bug on the side of facebook i think.

Answer (score 0):

Facebook does not handle the EXTRA_TEXT field. From this [bug report page](https://developers.facebook.com/x/bugs/332619626816423/#_=_) asking why "... the Facebook Android application is unable to accept the EXTRA_SUBJECT and EXTRA_TEXT fields," the answer was that:

"...our API does not support pre-filling the message for users as seen in our Policy Documentation here (https://developers.facebook.com/docs/guides/policy/application_integration_points/) under Platform Policy IV.2."