# Share to Facebook in android (like twitter)

Tags: android, facebook, android-intent, twitter, android-sharing

As anyone who's tried to share to Facebook via Android knows, the Facebook team has decided to disregard the protocol for sharing and ignores the text provided in the share intent (see: [Share Text on Facebook from Android App via ACTION_SEND](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3515198/share-text-on-facebook-from-android-app-via-action-send))

However, it appears that the twitter app has figured out how to circumvent this. When you're looking at a tweet:

[image: Twitter view]

You can click the share icon below the tweet and it brings up the normal share dialog with a list of apps, including Facebook:

[image: All the share icons, including Facebook that decided to screw over Android developers]

If you click on Facebook, you get this view:

[image: Damn you facebook. Damn you.]

Which looks perfect, and clearly twitter is sending more than just a link that other answers seem to propose. Furthermore, if you share to messaging:

[image: Good old messaging app. F___ facebook]

You can see that the text is properly added and there are no issues. How did twitter get this to work?

Comment: Is this the answer that you are looking for:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9730243/android-how-to-filter-specific-apps-for-action-send-intent

Comment: @arrowtop no, see the provided answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just to close out this question, I believe the way it works for Twitter in the example is based on the meta data available in the url provided. This is a good starting point: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/best-practices#tags

Answer (score 0):

If you're asking how you can include pre-fill text when sharing a link to Facebook from another app, this is actually directly against Facebook's policy -

"Ensure that all content in the user message parameter is entered by the user. Don’t pre-fill. This includes posts, messages, comments, and captions." (https://developers.facebook.com/policy/)

Comment: However the twitter app is still able to do this. (As well as iOS apps).

Answer (score 0):

what i did to over come the problem is little nasty but useful,

copy the text that want to be shared in clip board and

toast message "paste text",

### Copying to clipboard

```
@SuppressLint("NewApi")
private void copyToClipBoard(String data) 
{
    int sdk = android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT;
    if(sdk < android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB) 
    {
        android.text.ClipboardManager clipboard = (android.text.ClipboardManager) getActivity().getSystemService(Context.CLIPBOARD_SERVICE);
        clipboard.setText(data);
        Toast.makeText(context,"Paste text", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
    else 
    {
        android.content.ClipboardManager clipboard = (android.content.ClipboardManager) getActivity().getSystemService(Context.CLIPBOARD_SERVICE); 
        android.content.ClipData clip = android.content.ClipData.newPlainText(type,data);
        clipboard.setPrimaryClip(clip);
        Toast.makeText(context, "Paste text", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

}
```