# Share Data in android app for all applications

Tags: android, facebook, android-intent, mobile-application

How to Share Data(txt or image ....) in android for all applications

for example

[Share Data(txt or image ....) in android for all applications](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fgP9H.png)

the code not do on facebook

`Intent sendIntent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND);
sendIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "This is my text to send.");
sendIntent.setType("text/plain");
startActivity(Intent.createChooser(sendIntent, getResources().getText(R.string.send_to)));`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Share Text on Facebook from Android App via ACTION\_SEND](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3515198/share-text-on-facebook-from-android-app-via-action-send)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can only share links using an intent. you need Facebook Sdk to share text or images